# Proving $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ criterion for x cos x

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I'm trying to work out this problem:

> Let $f(x) = x cos x$. Prove that for every number $\epsilon > 0$, the
>   following statement is true:
>
> $If 0 < | x - 0 | < \epsilon$ then $|f(x) - 0 < \epsilon|$

This is my attempt:

Suppose $0 < |x - 0| < \epsilon$.
We know that $$|f(x) - 0| = |x cos x| = |x||cos x|$$
Since $$|x| < \epsilon $$

$$|x||cos x| < \epsilon |cos x|$$

Now I'm unable to proceed from here and stuck. How should this problem be approcached ?

Comment: Don't you know that $|\cos(x)|\leq 1$ ?

Comment: @Surb Yeah, I know that.

Comment: Then, what's the problem ?

Comment: @Surb Thanks, I think I got it now. Is the following reasoning correct: Since $cos(x) \leq 1$, we can conclude that $|x||cos x|$ < \epsion$ as $x > 0$ and $cos (x) <= 1$ ?

Comment: Not sure about the last sentence, but if $0<\varepsilon <\frac{\pi}{2}$ (this is important for $(*)$ below), $$|x||\cos(x)|\underset{(*)}{<}\varepsilon |\cos(x)|\leq \varepsilon ,$$ and thus $$|x||\cos(x)|<\varepsilon .$$